# ¿ Como evitar registros duplicados en una tabla relacionada?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola resulta que estoy en una encrucijada tengo tres tablas las cuales son post, tags y la relacion de post_tags.

En la relacion de post_tags algo parecido

| id | id_tags | id_post |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 60 |
| 2 | 6 | 60 |

El caso es que si hago un insert volviendo a ingresar el mismo id_tag digamos 5 este se vuelve a insertar quedando asi se repite el registro con un mismo id_tags

| id | id_tags | id_post |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 60 |
| 2 | 6 | 60 |
| 3 | 5 | 60 |

y teniendo en cuenta que las relaciones al ser de varios a varios no puedo agregar un indice unico entonces no encuentro la manera de hacer para que si un post ya tiene un tag asignado hacer que este no se vuelva a repetir.
Estaba probando con `INSERT IGNORE` pero al no haber indice unico no puedo hacer mayor cosa. Y en php no se me ocurre ninguna clase de validacion para evitar insertar el registro o registros duplicados

Answer (score 0):

Un constraint unique para que la BD valide la unicidad.

`ALTER TABLE pepito ADD UNIQUE unique_pepito_constraint(tag, post);`

Para hacerlo en PHP, pues haces un SELECT **antes de insertar** buscando ese tag y ese post, si el resultado del select trae más de *cero* registros, pues ya está en BD y no lo debes insertar.

Comment: hola gracias por responder no entiendo bien como funciona ALTER TABLE pepito ADD UNIQUE unique_pepito_constraint(tag, post); ya que en la tabla relacionada al ser valores de varios a varios ninguno puede tener un valor unico

Comment: @FerDaniela De acuerdo a tu ejemplo, lo que necesitas que sea único es la combinación de valores. Por eso el constraint se aplica sobre múltiples campos. Si definitivamente no te sirve, haz el select previo en PHP